# From code to golf (Cops' thread)

Tags: string, code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, source-layout, cops-and-robbers

*This is a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge, the robbers' thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241486/from-code-to-golf-robbers-thread)*

You can change the word `code` into `golf` by changing a letter at a time in four steps:

```
CODE
COLE
COLD
GOLD
GOLF
```

Today, we’ll be doing the same thing with programs.

Your challenge is to:

- choose a programming language
- write two programs / functions, one that outputs `code` and one that outputs `golf`
- Such that you can repeatedly change a single character and get a program that outputs an English word until you get to the `golf` program.
- Share the `code` program and the number of times you need to change a character, but not any of the intermediate programs or the `golf` program, which robbers will try to discover.
- No two programs can output the same word.

For example, if the program `abcde` outputs `code` in a certain language, and the program `abcdf` outputs `potato`, then changing that e to an f is a valid step.

And if the program `aqcdf` outputs `golf`, then `abcde` -> `abcdf` -> `aqcdf` is a valid chain in which you change a character twice.

You should only share the `code` program and the number of programs not counting the `code` program, the rest is for the robbers to guess.

Your solution is cracked when your entire chain of programs is found. It does not have to be your intended solution, only one with the same initial program and same or less length. (If someone finds a longer chain, it’s not a crack.)

If your answer is not cracked after a week, you may mark it as safe and reveal your solution.

Casing can be whatever you want - You can output `Code`, `CODE`, `coDe`, etc. Output may contain a trailing newline.

The dictionary used is `/dict/words`, which I've put in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/08d7f8c3bd773ea546d641a9f3051e22) for convenience.

### Scoring

Your score is the number of programs not counting the `code` or `golf` ones, multiplied by the length in bytes of your `code` program. The safe answer with the lowest score wins.

Comment: Do the words have to be distinct? As written it appears that I can have, say, 5 programs that all output `code` but are 1 character apart, and the final modification outputs `golf`

Comment: @NoOneIsHere As it says in the challenge body, No two programs can output the same word.

Comment: Oh I missed that, very sorry

Comment: Are hashing solutions considered cheesy/discouraged? Sorry if that's dumb, I'm new to cops and robbers challenges

Comment: @NoOneIsHere https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/19323#19323

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that one-letter words are allowed? (As long as they are included in the dictionary -- I didn't check if all of them are.)

Comment: @Arnauld Anything in the dictionary is allowed, so sure.

Comment: Some words appear twice in the dictionary differing only by capitalisation. Does this mean we can output both, and count them as separate words?

Comment: @pxeger: No. Capitalization is unimportant.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes, 4 changes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241565/58563) by Dom Hastings

Should be easier to crack than it was to build. :-p

There are 4 intermediate steps, for a total of 6 programs.

```javascript
_=>(0x63044+185886).toString(36)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k7DoMLM2MDERNvQwtTCwkxTryQ/uKQoMy9dw9hM839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241565/9365)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes, 1 step, [cracked by M Virts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241508/9288)

Let's start from an easy one.

```
go="co";lf="de";print(go,lf)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Pz3fVik5X8k6J81WKSVVybqgKDOvRCM9XycnTfP/fwA)

Comment: Was your intended solution to remove a character? (if so, you're supposed to change a character, not remove one).

Comment: @emanresuA No. Only changing one character to another.

Comment: Oh ok. Was asking because of [this crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241508/100664), which got deleted.\

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241508/100563

Comment: Lol beat me to it emanresu A

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes * 9 steps = score 63, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241649) by Dom Hastings

```
⍘⍘$zPγβ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUqkKOLf53Kb//wE) I had to use the full dictionary for this, because there is only one common word that is one source character away from the program for `golf` and that is `gold`, after which you would get stuck, however the words nearer the `code` end are less uncommon.

Comment: Did ye not find "Goof" for some reason?

Comment: @Joshua That's not one source character away from my `golf` program.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241649/9365)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 43 bytes, 15 changes: score 645: SAFE

17 steps total, 15 excluding `code` and `golf`.

Yeah, I don't think this one's going to be a winner! Might be too easy anyway, as I'm pretty sure there's a shorter route than the one I ended up taking but I couldn't quite get it working!

```perl
$_=$!=35;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$1.$3.$4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZF0dbY1FpfT0NPUw9MKAAJINK3Lk6sVDHSUzHUUzHWUzH5//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9QwM9AwA)

### Solution

I noticed that I could have saved a byte on my solution too using:

```perl
$_=$!=35;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say"$2$1$3$4"; # code
```

but only after posting and didn't think it was fair to adjust, a whole 15 off my score!

```perl
$_=$!=35;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$1.$3.$4; # code
$_=$!=35;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$1.$3.$4; # dode
$_=$!=35;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$1.$3.$1; # dodo
$_=$!=95;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$1.$3.$1; # nana
$_=$!=95;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$2.$3.$1; # nona
$_=$!=95;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$2.$3.$2; # nono
$_=$!=75;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$2.$3.$2; # lolo
$_=$!=75;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$4.$3.$2; # lalo
$_=$!=75;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$3.$4.$3.$3; # lall
$_=$!=75;/.(.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$5.$4.$3.$3; # all
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$5.$4.$3.$3; # off
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$5.$4.$5.$3; # of
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$5.$4.$5.$5; # o
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$4.$5.$5; # go
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$4.$4.$5; # goo
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$4.$4.$3; # goof
$_=$!=75;/ (.)..(.). (.)(.)/;say$2.$4.$1.$3; # golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc5BCsIwEIXhvaeImIUunDZJg0joETyDBNuIEDqldePljaXE0qw6gce/@@D17eB1CPxe832ttCngCCeYw6ZMK8xoP1wCF8AV8MqwA3tg0@42jUpMk2dENBjNlWo621mSkSuDWUZG8/92oRqPnmaqlbFZRkXjt41OTEoYhaBzVKIXkiH0LLaBTMCTLKpF5BAViaMasRjvQvhi/35hN4bzTYMoofwB)

I approached this by first [printing out all the 2 digit error messages](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJJd5KQUlHRdFWJV4hLb9IwdBAT8/S8v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9YCCBgA) and [looking for words that contained `g`, `o`, `l` and `f`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19F11YlXkdDJd5WRRHI0tTRT9dXU9PPBxE5ICINSBQnViqp6FopqMQrpeUXKRga6OlZWv7//y@/oCQzP6/4v66vqR5Q0AAA).
Once I had some target regexes [I checked if any of them would match `code`](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEEX3OcVYQlFpM7rookrBC3iCUktp0yBUExIXitSjG5OmbsRNPvOYzH@K6yGz9qC54HduoAChuQJkmMClUfAkALR2mC78U@@JA1gKOfQVW/9PhDh2W@5jDMULDJanwBkKPZMAylZ2vHKUjLDdMJbn7n4vNdDJB5Zfr1UQSSeH5MfJz9j6VkAZogvBZxUM9@bJNI@IpjunF4EvC81ktPYt1e0sr8amx4w5vPkA) and then refined to pick a regex that would have spaces in (at least some of) the right places.
From there I worked manually (because I found it interesting!) to pick a route, although automation would have probably resulted in a better score.

Comment: You're piecing together words from *error codes*... what...

Comment: Yes indeed! Combining Perl's two best features; weird variables that don't feel like they should work and regex!

Comment: this one should be safe now

Comment: @Razetime I thought I was waiting for the 30th! Or at least after 22:18 (GMT) on the 29th, but maybe that's me being overly stringent on the "week" stipulation! I'll hold off 'til Sunday for now, but I'm not sure if anyone's takenmuch of a look anyway! Thanks for the prompt though!

Comment: oh sorry i must've misread it

Comment: Nice! I got stuck at `trio` (35 -> 25). Was that intentional?

Comment: Not intentional at all! I did try to pick options with many words in (where I could!) to serve as both a distraction and a wider dictionary of attack. I got stuck somewhere myself when I was trying to find a path through and `trio` does sound familiar so maybe it is an easy trap to find!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes, 9 changes, [crick craked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241486/from-code-to-golf-robbers-thread/241511#241511) by Aaroneous Miller

```
«ƛ↔ƒ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCq8ab4oaUxpIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

This was kinda fun to create. I'll see what happens!

### Programs:

```
«ƛ↔ƒ outputs code
«ƛ↔ṙ outputs coal
«ƛ℅ṙ outputs fear
«ƛ℅ṫ outputs feat
«ƛFṫ outputs dent
«ƛF` outputs dell
«ƛ¾` outputs foci
`ƛ¾` outputs program
`ƛ₅` outputs then
`»₅` outputs golf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCq8ab4oaUxpLCqyxcbsKrxpvihpThuZnCqyxcbsKrxpvihIXhuZnCqyxcbsKrxpvihIXhuavCqyxcbsKrxptG4bmrwqssXG7Cq8abRmDCqyxcbsKrxpvCvmDCqyxcbmDGm8K+YCAsXG5gxpvigoVgICxcbmDCu+KChWAgLCIsIiIsIiJd) (last two characters of each line are to print)

Vyxal has two types of string compression. The first, delimited by `«`, takes the bytes within as a base-255 integer then converts that to base 27 and indexes it into a space plus the alphabet.

We switch through a bunch of these until we get to one where the last character is `` ` ``, allowing us to change the first character to `` ` `` to get into a dictionary compressed regular string.

Vyxal's dictionary compression is fairly simple - it replaces pairs of  non-ASCII characters with words from its dictionary, then remaining non-ASCII characters are replaced with words from a shorter dictionary.

This means that a string containing three characters shouldn't be able to return `golf`. But, I forgot that the short dictionary isn't complete (some slots aren't taken) and those just disappear, which Aaroneous's crack exploited.

Then, we iterate through a few words before getting to the 2-char compression code of `golf`.

Comment: [snap crackle pop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241511/101522)

Comment: @AaroneousMiller I see. Nice job, but I can't really build off what I have so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes, 3 changes, [cracked by M Virts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241508/9288)

Another easy one, using a similar trick.

```
g=c;f=e;l=d;print(g,o,l,f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P9022TrNNtU6xzbFuqAoM69EI10nXydHJ03z/38A)

M Virts found a simple answer with only two changes that I didn't expect. Here is my intended solution:

> `g=c;f=e;l=d;print(g,o,l,f)  /* code */`

> `g=c;f=e l=d;print(g,o,l,f)  /* cold */`

> `g c;f=e l=d;print(g,o,l,f)  /* gold */`

> `g c f=e l=d;print(g,o,l,f)  /* golf */`

Comment: ?? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241510/100563

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 13 bytes * 4 steps = score 52, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241486/from-code-to-golf-robbers-thread/241624#241624) by Dom Hastings

```
3130<202(^+@)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/f2NDYwMbIwEgjTttB8/9/AA)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241624/9365)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes, 5 steps: score 175: SAFE

7 steps total, 5 excluding `code` and `golf`.

```perl
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say$1.$2.$3.$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZF0dbUzFpfQ09TI18TSOpbFydWqhjqqRjpqRjrqaj///8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6meoYGeAQA)

---

When attempting to crack my own previous post, I noticed another way to crack it (using `"$2$1$3$4"` would have prevented this and also saved a byte...). Changing the variable names (as per some of the other posts) is both efficient and relatively straightforward with the right set of words. The regex match against the error is purely a red herring in this instance.

```perl
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say$1.$2.$3.$'; # code
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say$1.$2.$3.$f; # cod
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say$g.$2.$3.$f; # od
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say g.$2.$3.$f; # god
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say g.$2.$l.$f; # go
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say g.$2. l.$f; # gol
$_=$!=56;/(.)(o)(.)/;say g.$2. l. f; # golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZF0dbUzFpfQ09TI18TSOpbFydWqhjqqRjpqRjrqahbKygrJOenpHIRVpsGVYtbaTqKUjwqFVBVphNWmgNXSkClAkJlDmGlCjClaf///8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdooGcAAA)

Comment: If this is helpful for anyone cracking, [here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZF0dbU3FqhOLFSQSWei4srt1LBIVHBVkHDUE/P0MBA05orLb9IwyFRs5qLE6JcJR6uvJaLS1lfQ09TI18TSOpbA4VVjPVUjPRApDpQEm4BuipDuCoF5Zz8EgVdO4Wc/HwoVfL//7/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pkB36BkAAA) is a list of Perl error codes 1 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes * 2 steps = score 68, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241750/106959) by ThisFieldIsRequired

```python
golf="code"
goof="cold"
print golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Pz0/J81WKTk/JVWJKz0/H8zOSVHiKijKzCtRAMn@/w8A)

Easier than you think

Comment: [crack?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241750/106710)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes * 2 steps = 110 score, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241878/106959) by Aaron

```python
golf="code"
try:exec("print( golf )")
except:print("a")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pz0/J81WKTk/JVWJq6So0iq1IjVZQ6mgKDOvREMBJKmgqaTJlVqRnFpQYgURVkpU0vz/HwA)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241878/101522)