# From code to golf (Robbers' thread)

Tags: code-challenge, cops-and-robbers

*This is a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge, the cops' thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241485/from-code-to-golf-cops-thread)*

You can change the word `code` into `golf` by changing a letter at a time in four steps:

```
CODE
COLE
COLD
GOLD
GOLF
```

Today, we’ll be doing the same thing with programs.

Your challenge is to crack an answer on the cops' thread. Cops will create a series of programs in which the first prints `code`, the last prints `golf` and the rest print distinct English words such that each program can be derived from the previous by changing a single character of its code.

For example, if the program `abcde` outputs `code` in a certain language, and the program `abcdf` outputs `potato`, then changing that `e` to an `f` is a valid step.

And if the program `aqcdf` outputs `golf`, then `abcde` -> `abcdf` -> `aqcdf` is a valid chain in which you change a character twice.

The cops will only share the `code` program and the number of changes, your challenge is to figure out the rest. Once you discover their whole program chain, their answer is cracked.

Cops may output in any casing - `coDe`, `Code`, `CODe` etc.

The dictionary used is `/dict/words`, which I've put in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/08d7f8c3bd773ea546d641a9f3051e22) for convenience.

### Scoring

The user with the most cracks wins the cops challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), cracks [emanresu A’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241505/101522)

```
«ƛ↔ƒ
`ƛ↔ƒ
`ƛ₅ƒ
`»₅ƒ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCq8ab4oaUxpLCqyxcbmDGm+KGlMaSYCxcbmDGm+KChcaSYCxcbmDCu+KChcaSYCwiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Note: The final two characters in each line in the linked program is just so that each one can be ran alongside one another; they aren’t required for the individual programs.

The first change is changing the first character, which changes the compressed string into a dictionary compressed string. From this point on, because of the way that dictionary compression works in Vyxal, the final character in the string is ignored.

The next two changes are simply changing to the dictionary entry for `golf`. What’s convenient about using the dictionary is that most of it is made up of English words, so I didn’t have to worry much about how I changed those two characters, as long as I changed them to the correct characters.

I’m guessing the intended solution was probably more clever than just switching to dictionary compression, but I saw that the option was available and decided to take advantage of it.

Comment: Nice! I forgot the short dictionary has empty entries.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, [cracks Fmbalbuena's cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241748/106710) in two steps, not including  start and end

[Start for reference]

```py
golf="code"
goof="cold"
print golf
```

Step 1

```py
golf="code"
golf="cold"
print golf
```

Step 2

```py
golf="code"
golf="gold"
print golf
```

[End]

```py
golf="code"
golf="golf"
print golf
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), cracks [alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241503/100563)

Well someone has to do it...

One step:remove the comma.

```
go="co";lf="de";print(go,lf)

go="co";lf="de";print(go lf)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Pz3fVik5X8k6J81WKSVVybqgKDOvRCM9XyEnTfP/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 2 steps, cracks [alephalpha's second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241509/100563)

first spacify the first comma to output gode

```
g=c;f=e;l=d;print(g o,l,f)
```

then the last for golf

```
g=c;f=e;l=d;print(g o,l f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P9022TrNNtU6xzbFuqAoM69EI10hXydHIU3z/38A)

Comment: I really didn't expect this result

Comment: Wow!  I didn't see this obvious answer!

Comment: Is `gode` an English word?  I'm not finding it in online dictionaries...

Comment: @Jonah Not an answer to your question but it is a word in [French](https://youtu.be/nN4exktnhFQ)... (NSFW)

Comment: @emanresuA It's [included](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/08d7f8c3bd773ea546d641a9f3051e22#file-dictionary-L78502) in the gist linked in the cops' thread.

Comment: @Dingus Oops, missed it in my quick search.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), cracks [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241524/9365)

Didn't include `~` in my search originally which meant I got it in 7 programs...

```javascript
_=>(0x63044+185882).toString(36), // coda
_=>(0xd3044+185882).toString(36), // mice
_=>(0xd3044+~85882).toString(36), // gond
_=>(0xd3004+~85882).toString(36), // golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/R/NFW9rp2FQYWZsYGKibWhhamFhpqlXkh9cUpSZl65hbKapo6Cvr5AMUouh0gi7ykSomSn4VeZmJqeiqKzDpTI9Py8FodIAr8qcnP8YKi2wq0zjitVLyy9yTUzO0NBI01SwtQO6Pq84PydVLyc/XSNNQ1NT8z8A)

Used [this program](https://tio.run/##hZFhb9owEIY/J7/iJjFiL8aJCaSppvRb/8D2kbWra0yaysRtHKp2jP51dpBkggo2S2fZuudev3d@lC/Sqbp8akaVnevtduYHP/MrEr@mSTyZhCKbZllKeWO/N3VZFSRJacAgikAhfoIdn2Flz87/wy5LpY/Z97NsYav5ARv/mzXmBJudYRf@DV/Y@lqqB0JsXRZlJU3LUcivYO17ylaugT73TbuVaSAHol@k@VhCCf3q@95swmDKIGVwwSBjcMlAxBgCY4yRYCAikBEICaQEYmPkkvjAUNl78Gac8wBiMU4m0/QiuxyF0Rf@@Xb4W96ruV5U9vU9OCis9ZORSi911fyV8Jr6rT10Lbm9Z2zluAnuVveYImgY3w/hQAtvp9kSM4KyvbhXH4/IHY0GV7kA0jJ8KRu0G93O5OjXTTiIKAyH0NV/yvMPU6ed/b1/azQ3tiB3wWDdPrFpf3Ww7sQ74yT64cKoWDoGAQR0c4c@diIbv9/UzgW67fQBF@q455U26qGnNruy3Yax3f4B) combined with `grep`ing the dictionary to refine the results and then guesswork on which paths felt more likely to head towards `golf`!

Comment: Nice! `code > coda > mice > mick > mias > golf` also works.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, many solutions! Still needed that pesky `~` though! Thanks, this was fun!

Answer (score 2):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 3 steps, cracks [@Fmbalbuena's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241569/9365)

Using the list provided in the question:

- `3130<202(^+@)`: [code](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/f2NDYwMbIwEgjTttB8/9/AA)
- `3138<202(^+@)`: [cole](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/f2NDYwsbIwEgjTttB8/9/AA)
- `2138<202(^+@)`: [cold](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fyNDYwsbIwEgjTttB8/9/AA)
- `2138<242(^+@)`: [gold](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fyNDYwsbIxEgjTttB8/9/AA)
- `2338<242(^+@)`: [golf](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fyNjYwsbIxEgjTttB8/9/AA)

Comment: this is 4 steps, why 3?

Comment: Possibly I'm misinterpreting the rules!  I read "Your score is the number of programs not counting the code or golf ones" and assumed it only counts the ones that aren't `code` or `golf`! Happy to amend if I've got it wrong!

Comment: I changed the number of steps

Comment: +1 good crack, This is good.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for throwing you off with the steps! Was that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, Cracks [@Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241531/9365)

- [`⍘⍘$zPγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUqkKOLf53Kb//wE) - `code`
- [`⍘⍘$zZγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUqmKOrf53Kb//wE) - `codo`
- [`⍘⍘#zZγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUq6KOrf53Kb//wE) - `caul`
- [`⍘⍘#xZγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUq6IOrf53Kb//wE) - `cand`
- [`⍘⍘#xjγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgUq7IOrf53Kb//wE) - `cant`
- [`⍘⍘9xjγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgsqzIOrf53Kb//wE) - `nigh`
- [`⍘⍘9?jγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgsrTPOrf53Kb//wE) - `naga`
- [`⍘⍘,?jγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwg0rHPOrf53Kb//wE) - `girn`
- [`⍘⍘,hjγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwg0slIP7f53Kb//wE) - `goli`
- [`⍘⍘,hgγβ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwg0slIP7f53Kb//wE) - `golf`

Comment: As I mentioned, I was able to use less uncommon words on the `code` side: `coed`, `cava`, `cast` and `call`.

Comment: Although now I see that you were actually able to save a step, so never mind.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I did play around with a bunch of paths, but the `#` was the matching one for me! I got super obsessed with words that changed massively, like getting beryl but doing two searches simultaneously and looking for common chars was the most interesting to me. I've really enjoyed these!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, cracks [Fmbalbuena's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241877/101522)

```
golf="code"
try:exec("print( golf )")
except:print("a")
```

```
golf="code"
try:exec("print( golf')")
except:print("a")
```

```
golf="code"
try:exec("print('golf')")
except:print("a")
```

Adding the first `'` causes the `exec` to error, which goes to the except and prints `a`. After that, you can add the second `'`, which changes the contents of the `exec` to `print('golf')`, which outputs the target.